# PHPUnit Testing and woocommerce Constant

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, testing, unit-tests

I tried to perform a test on the `WC_VERSION` constant.

The main class :

```
class WC_Custom_Variable_Products_Dependencies {

    /** minimum WooCommerce version required by this plugin */
    const MINIMUM_WC_VERSION = '3.7.9';

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'admin_init', [$this, 'check_wc_version']);
    }

    protected function check_wc_version() {

         return  version_compare(WC_VERSION, self::MINIMUM_WC_VERSION , '>=');
    }
}
```

The test class :

```
 require_once 'includes/class-wc-custom-variable-products-dependencies.php';

 class WC_Custom_Variable_Products_DependenciesTest extends WP_UnitTestCase {

     public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->class_instance = new WC_Custom_Variable_Products_Dependencies();
     }

     /**
     * Tests the protected functions 
     * 
     * @param Object $method
     * @return bool
     */
    private function makeReflection($method) {

        $reflection = new ReflectionClass('WC_Custom_Variable_Products_Dependencies');
        $protectedMethod = $reflection->getMethod($method);
        $protectedMethod->setAccessible(true);

        return $protectedMethod->invokeArgs($this->class_instance, ['']);
    }
    public function test_check_wc_version() {

        $result = $this->makeReflection('check_wc_version');
        $this->assertTrue($result);
    }
}
```

And PHPunit return : 
`Use of undefined constant WC_VERSION - assumed 'WC_VERSION'`
does this mean in the test, Woocommerce is not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

`return defined('WC_VERSION');` should fix since `defined()` accepts a string as parameter.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php

If you use:
`require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');` adjusting your path if the installation is in a subrdir  you load all the WP environment including active plugins etc

Comment: yes i corrected that but now i have `Failed asserting that false is true.` means woocommerce is not active ?

Comment: I think you should post a more detailed code, these are just pieces

Comment: finally, I fixed the issue. simply load woocommerce sripts:  `require_once '../woocommerce/woocommerce.php';` . it 's a good practice or not ?

Comment: `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');` 
adjust your path if the installation is in a subrdir.
In this way you load all the WP environment